# WebSphere insert/update statements with SQL-SERVER hangs with REQUIRES_NEW propagation

Tags: websphere

We are facing an issue in our spring batch application when we are deploying the application on WebSphere.

Example: One class contains parent() method and Second class contains child() method, where child method requires a new transaction. After execution of the methods when transaction is committed the commit routine hangs and nothing happens further.

```
@Transactional //using current transaction
public void parent(){
    child();
}

@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW) //creates new transaction
public void child(){
//Database save statements including update, insert and deletes
}
```

This issue only persists in WebSphere and code works fine on our local machine where we are using tomcat as web container.

WebSphere logs/stacktrace shows that the WebSphere prepared statement keeps on waiting for the response from the database. At the same time update and inserts are locked out on the affected tables i.e. if we run an insert or update query manually on the affected table the query doesn't execute.

We are using Spring JPA for data persistence and Spring’s JpaTransactionManager for transaction management and MSSQLServer database.

Is it that WebSphere does not support creating new transaction from existing transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pattern you are describing is supported by WebSphere Application Server. Given that this involved locked entries within the database, you might be running into a difference between the application servers in which transaction isolation level is used by default.  In WebSphere Application Server, you get a default of java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ for SQL Server, whereas I think in most other cases you end up with a default of java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED (less locking).  If the default value is the problem, you can change it on the data source configuration.

If you are using WebSphere Application Server Liberty, then the default isolation level can be configured in server.xml as a property of the dataSource element, like this,

```
<dataSource isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" jndiName=...
```

If you are using WebSphere Application Server traditional, then the default isolation level can be configured as the webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel custom property, which can be set to the [numeric value of the isolation level constant on java.sql.Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED) (value for TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED is 2).
See [this linked article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWLGF_8.5.6/com.ibm.sr.doc/twsr_setwebspheredefaultisolationlevelproperty.html) for the steps of doing so via the admin console.

Comment: Thanks, changing default isolation level resolved the issue.